# Topological Entropy of $T$, on a disjoint union?

Tags: entropy

Let $X$ be a compact metric space and $T\colon X\to X$ continuous.

By $h(A\cup B\cup C,T_{|A\cup B\cup C})$ denote the toplogical entropy of $T$, restricted on $A\cup B\cup C$, where $A,B,C\subset X$ are disjoint.

Is then
$$
h(A\cup B\cup C,T_{|A\cup B\cup C})=h(A,T_{|A})+h(B,T_{|B})+h(C,T_{|C})?
$$
that is can the topological entropy of $T$ be "splitted up"?

I tried to find an answer but failed. Intuitively, I would think that this is true.

Comment: $h(A\cup B\cup C)=max\{ h(A),h(B),h(C)\}$.

Comment: But only if A,B, C are T-invariant...

Comment: I would guess that it is always true

Comment: if, say, $A$ is not $T$-invariant, what do you mean by $h(A,T_{|A})$? You need $A$ to be $T$-invariant for $T_{|A}$ to define a self-map of $A$. So, I think the question makes sense just under the assumption that your three spaces are invariant, so that you have well-defined restrictions.

Comment: $h(A\cup B\cup C,T_{|A\cup B\cup C})=h(A\cup B\cup C,T_{|A})+h(A\cup B\cup C,T_{|B})+h(A\cup B\cup C,T_{|C})=h(A,T_{|A})+h(B,T_{|B})+h(C,T_{|C})$

Comment: Then maybe, I wrote that down wrong. I think, I mean $h(A\cup B\cup C,T)$. Then the assumption is not true, isn't it? Anyhow, I do not see why $A,B,C$ should be invariant under T.

Answer (score 0):

Using this definition of a [restricted topology](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=a3BFcnmGM4oC&pg=PA175&lpg=PA175&dq=restricted%20topology&source=bl&ots=VXdA_zHdSO&sig=VIbJoA1K1j83xEpxKUdt4oGGG8g&hl=en&sa=X&ei=_RZzVfCPDsPg7Qbg4oKYBg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=restricted%20topology&f=false), we can state that:

$$h(A∪B∪C,T|_{A∪B∪C})$$

$$=\;h(A∪B∪C,T|_A)\;+\;h(A∪B∪C,T|_B)\;+h\;(A∪B∪C,T|_C)$$

$$=\;h(A,T|_A)\;+\;h(B,T|_B)\;+\;h(C,T|_C)$$